# Need to get specific information from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am stuck and need some help, I am using the entity framework and have the following browse ActionResult that creates a list of shows:

```
  public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
    {
        var genreModel = db.Genres.Include("Shows")
        .Single(g => g.Name == genre);

        return View(genreModel);
    }
```

This is the list of shows:

```
@foreach (var show in Model.Shows)
{
    <li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = show.ShowId })"> 
    <img alt="@show.Title" src="@show.ShowArtUrl" /> <span>@show.Title</span> </a>   
    </li>
    }
```

I need to create the Details ActionResult that will respond when the user clicks on the link taking the ShowId as shown above and return the details of the show, anyone?

Comment: I have this so far: Public ActionResult Details (int id){ Missing the body} return View()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how I accomplished what you are trying to do (or at least what I think you are trying to do).

Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<DarkRobot.Models.Post>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
        <aside class="blogAside">
            <h3>history of words</h3>
            <ul class="linkList">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Reverse())
            {
                string name = item.Title;
                <li><a>@Html.ActionLink(name, "Details", new { id = item.Id }, null)</a></li>
            }
            </ul>
        </aside>
```

Here I have the @Html.Actionlink that is grabbing the id of each of the blog posts I have. So when the link is created it is passing in that value the my other view "Details"

The Controller handles all this stuff so here is that:

Index:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var posts = db.Posts.Include(p => p.Blog).Include(p => p.Comments);
        return View(posts.ToList());
    }
```

And now the details Controller:

```
    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        return View(post);
    }
```

In the ViewResult for my Details view, I make sure that I take the id that was passed in and assign it to the post I am pulling up.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Also, to clarify a bit, instead of doing <a href="@Url you can just doing @ActionLink and MVC will automatically generate the link markup for you.

Comment: I am trying to implement what you have suggested

Comment: I am having an error within the details view:  <em>Genre:</em>
    @Model.Genre.Name
    </p> is returning a null reference?

Comment: Can you post the view so I can see it?

Comment: My mistake I needed to change the view code to: <em>Genre:</em>
    s.Genre.Name
    </p>

Comment: False alarm its not working: View Code is model U0858987_PennineTheatre_Component_2.Models.Show

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show " + Model.Title;
}

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>

<div id = "browse">
    <p>
        <img alt="@Model.Title" src="@Model.ShowArtUrl" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <em>Genre:</em>
    @Model.Genre.Name
    </p>


</div>

Comment: I had this same problem last night, and I got it to work, but I don't have access to the computer I did it on. I think you are on the right track, and I will look at my working code this evening to figure out the step we are missing.

Comment: That is very kind of you, much appreciated

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if it makes more sense now and works for you. Cheers